# Gradle commandLine task not executing

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

```
task runSwig(type:Exec, dependsOn: ['createCoreWrapperDir']) {
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if (osName.contains("windows")) {
    workingDir '/src/main/jni'   // This implicitly starts from $(projectDir) evidently
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'swig'
    args '-c++', '-java', '-package', 'com.sureshjoshi.core', '-outdir', coreWrapperDir.absolutePath, 'SeePlusPlus.i'
}
else {
  commandLine "swig"
    args "-c++", "-java", "-package","com.sureshjoshi.core","-outdir", coreWrapperDir.absolutePath, "${projectDir}/src/main/jni/SeePlusPlus.i"
    println "running task"
}}
```

gradle build run without error, but the task in 'else' (commandLine "swig") didnt run (running the command in terminal works). the println did output "running task" in the console. So gradle did enter the else loop.

the command is supposed to execute 'swig' to output wrapped cpp files into the folder specified.

is there any syntax error in the codes?

p.s: the codes are taken from http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-ndk-in-android-studio-with-swig/

Comment: According to the code the else part will only execute if osName will not contain "windows". Did you check the value of osName on your system?

Comment: 'println osName' returns: mac os x  (yes i'm on OS X Yosemite)

Comment: Is it possible that swig is not available in your path so when gradle tries to execute this command it doesn't find it? You can try adding a workingDir property with the path to swig in order to check this out

Comment: most likely you need to run this command in a bash/zsh? so you need to configure your commandline to run of of those like you do with cmd.exe on windows

Comment: @ReneGroeschke, tried it that way, didnt work.

Comment: @AmnonShochot, i tried calling swig directly using absolute path (/usr/local/bin/swig), still no intended output.